# lightbox doesn't load Facebook plugin after close

Tags: jquery, facebook, lightbox

i have this script:

```
<a id="editprofile" href="#edit_profile">123</a>
<div style="display: none;">
<div id="edit_profile" style="width:640px;height:auto;overflow:auto;">
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"> </script><fb:comments href="apps.facebook.com/conteststwenty/" num_posts="2" width="620"></fb:comments>
</div>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$("#editprofile").fancybox({
      'titlePosition'        : 'inside',
     'transitionIn'        : 'none',
     'transitionOut'        : 'none'
 });
```

or see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/muHXe/3/).

what happens is that i have a simple Facebookplugin loading inside (could be any FB plugin)

and after I close the lightbox the second time I open it the plugin doesn't appear. Any ideas how to make it work, or maybe suggest another lightbox that will go the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @WTK is right about the `src` attribute and Fancybox behavior. Altering the library source is a **BAD** practice and the last thing you may do. A better approach could be using the `onStart` event:

```
$("#editprofile").fancybox({
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'onStart': saveSrc,
});
var src = '';
var $commentsContainer = $("#edit_profile");
function saveSrc() {
    if(!src) {
        // First time here, we still have the src attribute so 
        // grab it and save it for later!
        src = $commentsContainer.find('iframe').attr('src');
    } else {
        $commentsContainer.find('iframe').attr('src', src)
    }
}
```

Also you shouldn't be adding the `fb-root` and the Facebook JS library to the lightbox.
**Demo:** [link](http://jsfiddle.net/muHXe/5/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing the second time, because fancybox onclose handler resets the *src* attribute of any iframe it finds in its content. So next time you open the fancybox the iframe which suppose to have FB content has src

To overcome this, you can comment out following line in fancybox js src:

```
content.find('iframe').attr('src', isIE6 && /^https/i.test(window.location.href || '') ? 'javascript:void(false)' : 'about:blank');
```

Check updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/muHXe/4/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both the solutions given.. you can try this too

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var mySRC = "";
$("#editprofile").fancybox({
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'onComplete': function() {
        mySRC = $('#edit_profile iframe').attr('src');
    },
    'onClosed': function() {
        $('#edit_profile iframe').attr('src', mySRC);

    }
});
});
```

here is a fiddle for ur prob
http://jsfiddle.net/muHXe/7/